# Using NSTemporaryDirectory to write video files

Tags: ios, swift, directory

In my app, users are allowed to record videos up to 20 minutes long. When I start the AVCaptureSession, it writes the movie file to a temporary directory. I was just wondering if this was a bad habit and using a temporary directory is not good for long videos.

If this is not a good method to do so, where else should I write the videos? This is what my function looks like.

```
func videoFileLocation() -> String {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = .long
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = .long
    let date = dateFormatter.string(from: Date())

    return NSTemporaryDirectory().appending("video\(date)File.mov")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use Document directory .

```
func videoFileLocation() -> String {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = .long
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = .long
    let date = dateFormatter.string(from: Date())
    let documents = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as! String
    let writePath = documents.stringByAppendingPathComponent("video\(date)File.mov")
    return writePath
}
```